# Update widget by changing text

Tags: android

Hello friends I am trying to update a widget every user changes the text of  texview Anyone can tell me how to do that? I do not know how to do it.

```
   public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(MyService.NEW_DATA)) {

        RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        remote.setTextViewText(R.id.txtValue, text)
        ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remote);
        }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you call 
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
Try not calling it. Everything else looks fine.